# Uncaught (in promise) Error: No ethereum object at checkIfTransactionsExists (TransactionContext.jsx:105:13)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-dom

Here is my TransactionContext.jsx

TransactionContext.jsx:105 Uncaught (in promise) Error: No ethereum object
at checkIfTransactionsExists (TransactionContext.jsx:105:13)

[image]

Error: No ethereum object
at sendTransaction (TransactionContext.jsx:159:13)
[image]

I Have established an Solidity content in order to provide Ether object

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { ethers } from "ethers";

import { contractABI, contractAddress } from "../utils/constants";

export const TransactionContext = React.createContext();

const { ethereum } = window;

function disp_alert(){
  if (confirm("Please install metamask"))
   window.open("https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/metamask/nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn?hl=en" ,  '_blank');}

const createEthereumContract = () => {
  const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(ethereum);
  const signer = provider.getSigner();
  const transactionsContract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, contractABI, signer);

  return transactionsContract;
};

export const TransactionsProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [formData, setformData] = useState({
    addressTo: "",
    amount: "",
    keyword: "",
    message: "",
  });
  const [currentAccount, setCurrentAccount] = useState("");
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [transactionCount, setTransactionCount] = useState(
    localStorage.getItem("transactionCount")
  );
  const [transactions, setTransactions] = useState([]);

  const handleChange = (e, name) => {
    setformData((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, [name]: e.target.value }));
  };

  const getAllTransactions = async () => {
    try {
      if (ethereum) {
        const transactionsContract = createEthereumContract();

        const availableTransactions =
        await transactionsContract.getAllTransactions();

      const structuredTransactions = availableTransactions.map(
        (transaction) => ({
          addressTo: transaction.receiver,
          addressFrom: transaction.sender,
          timestamp: new Date(
            transaction.timestamp.toNumber() * 1000
          ).toLocaleString(),
          message: transaction.message,
          keyword: transaction.keyword,
          amount: parseInt(transaction.amount._hex) / 10 ** 18,
        })
      );

        console.log(structuredTransactions);

        setTransactions(structuredTransactions);
      } else {
        console.log("Ethereum is not present");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  const checkIfWalletIsConnect = async () => {
    try {
      if (!ethereum) return disp_alert();

      const accounts = await ethereum.request({ method: "eth_accounts" });

      if (accounts.length) {
        setCurrentAccount(accounts[0]);

        getAllTransactions();
      } else {
        console.log("No accounts found");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  const checkIfTransactionsExists = async () => {
    try {
      if (ethereum) {
        const transactionsContract = createEthereumContract();
        const currentTransactionCount = 
          await transactionsContract.getTransactionCount();

        window.localStorage.setItem(
          "transactionCount", 
          currentTransactionCount
          );
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);

      throw new Error("No ethereum object");
    }
  };

  const connectWallet = async () => {
    try {
      if (!ethereum)  return disp_alert();

      const accounts = await ethereum.request({ method: "eth_requestAccounts", });
     
      setCurrentAccount(accounts[0]);
      window.location.reload();
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);

      throw new Error("No ethereum object");
    }
  };

  const sendTransaction = async () => {
    try {
      if (ethereum) {
        const { addressTo, amount, keyword, message } = formData;
        const transactionsContract = createEthereumContract();
        const parsedAmount = ethers.utils.parseEther(amount);

        await ethereum.request({
          method: "eth_sendTransaction",
          params: [{
            from: currentAccount,
            to: addressTo,
            gas: "0x5208",
            value: parsedAmount._hex,
          }],
        });

        const transactionHash = await transactionsContract.addToBlockchain(addressTo, parsedAmount, message, keyword);

        setIsLoading(true);
        console.log(`Loading - ${transactionHash.hash}`);
        await transactionHash.wait();
        console.log(`Success - ${transactionHash.hash}`);
        setIsLoading(false);

        const transactionsCount = await transactionsContract.getTransactionCount();

        setTransactionCount(transactionsCount.toNumber());
        window.location.reload();
      } else {
        console.log("No ethereum object");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);

      throw new Error("No ethereum object");
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    checkIfWalletIsConnect();
    checkIfTransactionsExists();
  }, [transactionCount]);

  return (
    <TransactionContext.Provider
      value={{
        transactionCount,
        connectWallet,
        transactions,
        currentAccount,
        isLoading,
        sendTransaction,
        handleChange,
        formData,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </TransactionContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Here I resolve this error by

correcting my smart_contract deploy.js

and finally there was an correction over on my contract_address